# GWT maven project with server side dependencies

Tags: gwt, maven, jasper-reports, conflict

I have a maven GWT project under eclipse and since I added some server side dependencies the maven plugin doesn't compile anymore. Here follows more info about the context:

- maven 3.0.3;
- GWT 1.5.3;
- GWT maven plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.2 (the latest compatible with GWT 1.5.3, http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin-1.2/).

The goal gwt:compile of the GWT maven plugin completes successfully if I don't add dependencies other than the GWT ones:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I add any other dependency, the goal gwt:compile fails:

```
[INFO] establishing classpath list (scope = compile)
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IErrorHandlingPolicy;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ICompilerRequestor;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IProblemFactory;)V
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.<init>(JdtCompiler.java:93)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.<init>(JdtCompiler.java:231)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.compile(JdtCompiler.java:193)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationState.compile(CompilationState.java:115)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler.distill(GWTCompiler.java:327)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler.run(GWTCompiler.java:564)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler.run(GWTCompiler.java:554)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler.main(GWTCompiler.java:214)
```

I did search a configuration parameter about classpath/dependencies in the gwt:compile (http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin-1.2/compile-mojo.html) with no success.

I would like to use server side dependencies alongside GWT ones telling the GWT plugin to not consider the non-GWT dependencies.

---

working pom (gwt:compile completes successfully):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project name</name>

    <organization>
        <name>My company</name>
        <url>my company url</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <gwt.version>1.5.3</gwt.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>final name</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <ajdtVersion>none</ajdtVersion>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>org.mycompany.myproject.Main/welcomeGWT.html</runTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- GWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

not working pom (gwt:compile throws exception):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project name</name>

    <organization>
        <name>My company</name>
        <url>my company url</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <gwt.version>1.5.3</gwt.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>final name</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <ajdtVersion>none</ajdtVersion>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>org.mycompany.myproject.Main/welcomeGWT.html</runTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.726</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- GWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: Can you show both working and non-working pom.xml files?

Comment: Easy solution - move GWT dependencies to be the first in the list of all dependencies.

Comment: Still fails, with the same error: after having moved dependencies I made an eclipse:clean, so eclipse and then gwt:compile.

Comment: Then comment out first/second and find out which one causes build to fail.

Comment: The dependency giving problems is jasper reports, but I don't understand why. It's obvious that I don't know something. I was wrongly sure that te problem was a conflict between non-GWT compliant dependencies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using JasperReport in our project? I remember having a problem using JasperReport and GWT. JasperReport includes a different version of the  `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler` than what GWT is expecting.

I think you can fix this by simply changing the order of the class path (was already suggested in the comments). If that does not help, try to update your GWT version. Or try to find a version of JasperReport which includes a version of the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compile` class that works with GWT.

Comment: Yes, I use jasper reports and excluding that dependency the problem doesn't occur. `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler` seems to be an eclipse class, jasper shouldn't deal with that stuff. Do you remember also the "under the hood" of this problem?

Comment: Following your hint I started searching in this direction, and found this: http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=4729. Here "lucianc" suggests to esclude the eclipse:jdtcore dependency from jasper reports. Doing this it compiles! Maybe now this is offtopic, but I would like to understand why it downloads the eclipse:jdtcore dependency. Maybe this issue is related to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-219.

Comment: Uff... That was quite a while ago... Look for the two files jasper-compiler-jdt.jar and jasper-jdt.jar. Both contain the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler` class. The jasper-jdt.jar is shipped with Tomcat which is part of the hosted mode. I'm quite sure if you move to a later version of GWT the problem will go away, since newer GWT versions do not include Tomcat anymore.

Comment: I see: now I'm wondering if that dependency exclusion will lead to side effects. For the moment I found a workaround, it would be great to understand all the details. Why jasper reports needs that compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error in our QA **Linux** environment during deployment of our web application and we managed to fix it. This problem wasn't even there when I deployed into my local **Windows 10** and **Linux Ubuntu** virtual machine. My environment configuration is as follows

1. **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**
2. **Apache Maven 3.3.3**
3. **Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)**
4. **JVM 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14**

The problem was because there were two eclipse Compiler classes that were found in two different jar files, and this creates conflicts in the classpath during tomcat deployment. The culprits are files ecj.jar and jdtcore.jar

My original pom.xml snipet is as below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

1. The **Maven** dependency tree for drools-compiler introduces ecj.jar file.
2. The **Maven** dependency for dynamicreports-core.jar file that has jasperreports.jar that in turn introduces jdtcore.jar file.

**Solution:**

We upgraded the version of dynamicreports-core that introduces jasperreports.jar file.

**Note:**
I was able to fix this issue after reading http://www.cnblogs.com/xiaoMzjm/p/4566672.html. Credits to this blogger.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```